# Does Nekros’ shadows of the dead damage increase based on the level of the shadows?

Tags: warframe

For example, you kill 7 level 80 grinder lancers, and then use shadows of the dead. Is the only thing that can increase damage ability strength mods? Or does the damage also increase based on the levels of the shadows? I am not really sure how the ability works so could somebody give me an explanation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wikia says:

> The copies retain the level and stats of their original selves but
> will gain 25% / 50% / 75% / 150% damage

So, yes, damage and other stats of your shadows increase with enemy level.